# TP4056 and Li-ion batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I have several 3.7 V 1800 mAh and 700 mAh Li-ion pouch batteries that also have the [8205A](https://www.ablic.com/en/doc/datasheet/battery_protection/S8205A_B_E.pdf) and [DW01A](http://www.hmsemi.com/downfile/DW01A.PDF) chips mounted to the top.

I've seen two types of [TP4056](http://www.tp4056.com/d/tp4056.pdf) boards (one with these two chips for Li-ion pouch batteries with "protect" printed on the back and the kind without the chips designed for Li-ion batteries) and I'm wondering if the Li-ion pouch batteries that have these components are compatible with the TP4056 board for Li-ion cylindrical batteries.

From what I've read so far the TP4056 will only charge batteries greater than 1000 mAh so the 700 mAh batteries might be out of the question.

I've tried to find the answer on other forums regarding the Li-ion battery protection circuit mounted on the battery as opposed to the TP4056 but so far I've found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The spec shows a current source PROG and sink, BAT, with an equation of $$I_{Bat}= 1200*V_{PROG}/R_{PROG}$$ so for  $$ V_{PROG}=1\ \mathrm{V}, I_{BAT}=700\ \mathrm{mA}, R_{PROG}=1200/0.7\ \mathrm{A}$$

**The limit is *not* 1000 mAh min *rather* it is 1000 mA maximum.**

The TEMP pin must be terminated properly and all other suggested circuit conponents.

Are there any other specs that need explanation?

```
·Input Supply Voltage(V CC )：-0.3V～8V
·TEMP：-0.3V～10V
·CE：-0.3V～10V
·BAT Short-Circuit Duration：Continuous
·BAT Pin Current：1200mA
·PROG Pin Current：1200μA
·Maximum Junction Temperature：145℃
·Operating Ambient Temperature Range：-40℃～85℃
·Lead Temp.(Soldering, 10sec)：260℃
```

Comment: Well, my question is if the Lipo battery has the protection circuit (8205A MOSFET and DW01a) built into it then can I use the regular TP4056 instead of the TP4056 "protect" model?

Comment: @MatthewOlson he corrected this statement: `From what I've read so far the TP4056 will only charge batteries greater than 1000mah so the 700mah batteries might be out of the question`

Comment: Not so, you can set Iprog as low as you want, but shall not exceed the suggested limit for thermal reasons.

Comment: TP4056 board with or without DW01 should work with battery with DW01 connected on discharge. This functions only at Vbat_min so should not affect charging. Depending how the battery drive cct is connected it MAY have issues starting charging but probably not. You only need one LV cutout so the battery one could be bypassed if you TP4056 also has one.